# add oci.dll oracle client to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have read that to connect to oracle, besides add oracle.dataaccess.dll to the reference, vb.Net program have to add :

- oci.dll
- OraOps11w.dll
- oraociei11.dll
- msvcr71.dll

But I can't add to the reference. How to add those files to my vb.net program actually?

Comment: No, you have to reference only `oracle.dataaccess.dll`. The DLL itself will load the other DLL's you mentioned.

Comment: It's not work when I install the program on user pc. Error with the oracle.dataaccess.dll, but if I install the oracle client too, all is well. Have so many users by the way

Comment: Yes, if you like to use `oracle.dataaccess.dll` then you also have to install at least the Oracle Instant Client. Another solution is to use the ODP.NET Managed Driver (see answer from Cyrille MODIANO), then you have to supply only single DLL `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`

Comment: oo I see.. thanks sir Wernfried Domscheit

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to download ODP.net from:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Then add a reference to your project named Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Here is a sample code to connect to the db and retrieve data:

```
Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=orcl;User Id=hr;Password=hr;"
Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb) 
conn.Open()
Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "select department_name from departments where department_id = 10"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
dr.Read()
Label1.Text = dr.Item("department_name")
conn.Dispose()
```

Comment: That is correct if you use the ODP.NET Managed Driver. However, maybe there is a specific reason why TO uses the unmanaged driver.

Comment: It means I have to changes the code, too risk. Maybe I'll just save it for later. Thanks